# Zod: Validate conditionally an `array of objects` with a key of object[i]

Tags: schema, zod

Considering the following `body`:

```
{
  ....: ...
  type: ['url', 'email', 'other']
  data: ['aaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc' ]
  ...: ....
}
```

I'd like to check/parse/validate with custom error message if:

- `aaa` is an `url`
- `bbbbb` is an `email`
- `ccccc` is a `string`

At this time, I have without any more idea:

```
type: z.array(z.enum(['url', 'email', 'other'], { errorMap: () => ({ message: 'CANNOT_BE_EMPTY' }) })),
data: z.array(z.string()).refine(el => {?????})
```

Any clue to validate conditionaly this object?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to access both `type` and `data` in `refine`, move the refinement to the outer object:

```js
const Schema = z
  .object({
    type: z.array(
      z.enum(['url', 'email', 'other'], {
        errorMap: () => ({ message: 'CANNOT_BE_EMPTY' }),
      })
    ),
    data: z.array(z.string()),
  })
  .refine(/* ... */)
```

Something like this:

```js
const UrlSchema = z.string().url()
const EmailSchema = z.string().email()

const Schema = z
  .object({
    type: z.array(
      z.enum(['url', 'email', 'other'], {
        errorMap: () => ({ message: 'CANNOT_BE_EMPTY' }),
      })
    ),
    data: z.array(z.string()),
  })
  .refine((object) => object.type.length === object.data.length, {
    message: '`type` and `data` arrays should have equal length',
  })
  .refine((object) =>
    object.type.every((type, i) => {
      const data = object.data[i]
      if (type === 'url') return UrlSchema.safeParse(data).success
      if (type === 'email') return EmailSchema.safeParse(data).success
      return true // Definitely a string; checked by the `z.array(z.string())` above
    })
  )
```

Though for the second refinement you probably want to use [Zod's `superRefine` method](https://zod.dev/?id=superrefine) to be able to specify separate error messages for each failure. Something like this (notice that I changed `object.type.every` to `object.type.forEach`):

```js
const UrlSchema = z.string().url()
const EmailSchema = z.string().email()

const Schema = z
  .object({
    type: z.array(
      z.enum(['url', 'email', 'other'], {
        errorMap: () => ({ message: 'CANNOT_BE_EMPTY' }),
      })
    ),
    data: z.array(z.string()),
  })
  .refine((object) => object.type.length === object.data.length, {
    message: '`type` and `data` arrays should have equal length',
  })
  .superRefine((object, ctx) => {
    object.type.forEach((type, i) => {
      const data = object.data[i]
      if (type === 'url' && !UrlSchema.safeParse(data).success) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          message: 'Invalid URL',
          path: ['data', i],
        })
      } else if (type === 'email' && !EmailSchema.safeParse(data).success) {
        ctx.addIssue({
          code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
          message: 'Invalid email',
          path: ['data', i],
        })
      }
    })
  })

const body = {
  type: ['url', 'email', 'other'],
  data: ['aaa', 'bbbbb', 'ccccc'],
}

Schema.parse(body)
//=> error: Uncaught ZodError: [
//     {
//       "code": "custom",
//       "message": "Invalid URL",
//       "path": [
//         "data",
//         0
//       ]
//     },
//     {
//       "code": "custom",
//       "message": "Invalid email",
//       "path": [
//         "data",
//         1
//       ]
//     }
//   ]
```